# unable to call and manipulate external api in node js using request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I am trying to call [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos] in my node codes so that i create an end-point that is dynamic...like if i change 1 in url i get the relevant photos.

here are my codes

```js
const request = require('request');

const callExtrenalApiUsingRequest = async (callback, req, res) => {
        try {
             let id = req.params.id
       await request(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${id}/photos`, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
           if (err) {
                return callback(err);
           }
           return callback(body)

        })
        }
    catch (error){
 console.log(error)
}

}
module.exports.callApi = callExtrenalApiUsingRequest;
```

#### request.js

```js
const apiCallFromRequest = require( './request.js');
const http = require('http')

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    try {
        if (req.url === "/request/photos/:id") {
            apiCallFromRequest.callApi(function (response) {
                res.write(JSON.stringify(response));
                res.end();
        
            })
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}).listen(3000)
console.log("service running on port 3000...")
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding any errors you are getting, it's good to show the debugging you have done so far.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend wrapping `await request(args...)` in a variable, processing it, and then returning it upon success. This will give you more control over the response logic. Alternatively, look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises), this gives more structure for async functionality.

Comment: @Alex thanks...but my issue is that however much I am trying to catch errors  i am getting none i.e nothing is being displayed